# ROS Wiki crumbtrail navigation is odd

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble navigating the Turtlebot wiki and it seems mainly due to the crumbtrail structure.

Example page: http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro

Has this crumbtrail: turtlebot_calibration / Tutorials / Calibrate Odometry and Gyro

I would expect that clicking Turtorials would crawl up to the list of all tutorials. Or the root of the crumbtrail would point here:
http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_apps

Perhaps I'm just a wiki idiot? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28023/ros-wiki-crumbtrail-navigation-is-odd/) by [Ryan Hickman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1822/ryan-hickman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each tutorial is listed under it's primary package, so if the tutorial is specifically about turtlebot_calibration then the tutorials is placed in the path turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/your_tutorial. The thing you're calling the "crumb trail" is actually just the wiki path not the crumb trail from whence you came. If you'd like a crumb trail implemented in the wiki, you'll probably need to file a ticket to make it happen.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1